# How do you spawn application from tcl/tk such that it's independant of the parent app?

Tags: tcl, expect, tk-toolkit

I've tried just about EVERYTHING. I've tried exec. I've tried open with a pipe. I've tried expect's spawn command. I've even tried creating scripts that launch the application. None of this works. It should be something so freaking simple but it isn't. Basically I want something that executes "./myapp &". I don't want the parent app to wait for any input. I don't want the parent app to kill the child when it's closed. Nor do I want the closure of the child to affect the parent.

I've spent 4 hours trying to do this with no dice.

EDIT 4: I have produced a small test case. Actually. I know think the bug is related to a shell script called from tcl not recognizing it's finished and wanting more input. But oddly, the script does run and the following tcl commands are still executed.

Create a file called "data.dat"

```
9.2877556131E+03 1.2512862771E-15 1.5337670739E-18
9.2910873127E+03 1.2439911921E-15 1.5339531650E-18
9.2944190123E+03 1.2253566905E-15 1.5354833054E-18
9.2977507119E+03 1.2115157273E-15 1.6142496743E-18
9.3010824115E+03 1.2080944425E-15 1.7533261348E-18
9.3044141111E+03 1.2076649858E-15 1.8405304542E-18
9.3077458106E+03 1.1904275879E-15 1.8336914953E-18
9.3110775102E+03 1.1790369061E-15 1.8270892064E-18
9.3144092098E+03 1.1620102216E-15 1.8244075829E-18
9.3177409094E+03 1.1178361307E-15 1.8581382655E-18
9.3210726090E+03 1.0969704027E-15 1.8237852087E-18
9.3244043086E+03 1.0721326432E-15 1.7016959482E-18
9.3277360082E+03 1.0699729320E-15 1.6841145916E-18
9.3310677078E+03 1.0266229217E-15 1.7253936877E-18
9.3343994074E+03 9.0875918248E-16 1.6065954292E-18
9.3377311069E+03 7.9157363851E-16 1.5220001484E-18
```

and then run this tcl file on it

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

frame .main
button .button -text "Make plot" -command { makeplot }
pack .button

proc makeplot {} {

set data {#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF > plot.gnu
splot "data.dat" using 1:2:3 with points
EOF
}

set fileId [open "plot.csh" "w"]
puts -nonewline $fileId $data
flush $fileId
close $fileId
exec chmod +x ./plot.csh
exec ./plot.csh
exec gnuplot -persist < plot.gnu &

}
```

The gnuplot plot will not appear until you "foreground" it. I have tried many variations on this (with/without the ampersand). Strangely, I DID get a version of this working under bash.

EDIT 5: I GIVE UP! This test case is now working. It was not just moments ago. I have NO idea what's going on here. This has been one of the hardest bugs to fix in 15 years of programming.

Comment: I now have a method that works. It seems very ugly. I'd be interested in seeing if I invented a Rube Goldberg machine in the process.

Comment: (Actually it my method doesn't fully work. It has timing problems.)

Answer (score 4):

Try `exec` with `&` at the end:

```
exec ./myapp &
```

Comment: This was among the first things I tried. It has problems. The backgrounded application does not appear unless the parent TCL app is running in the foreground.

Comment: @Dr. Person Person II: Perhaps you could provide some more information about your application and expectations?  The solution I posted works as expected, regardless of the foreground status of the original application.  Maybe your second process actually requires TTY input, so it's blocked because when you start it in the background it's detached from the TTY?

Comment: The application I was trying to spawn was merely a gnuplot script. That's it. The above solution does not work,  not even with the xeyes program. It still hangs the application and prints " + Suspended (tty output)" to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried piping to 'at now'?
        ./myapp | at now